# kernel roll-out roster for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, updates, hardware-enablement-stack

**Where** can I find the roll-out roster for the Ubuntu kernel, showing both GA and HWE versions of linux-image kernels?

Ideally there should be (somewhere) a *maintained* table with Ubuntu realease versions, and dates for both GA and HWE roll-outs.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 it is half of what I am looking for. I was hoping to see current HWE linux-image versions somehow superimposed on the graphs for releass up to date.

Comment: I do not quite get what you want. But did you look at all graphs?

Comment: +1 @Pilot6 Sorry I consigned my comment and then was too slow (> 5 min) in my editing to correct it. It should read: "exactly what I was looking for!". I have already gone from 14.04.1 v 13.13 to 14.04.2 v 3.16.0-41. Do post that link as answer so I can check it as such.

Comment: I added link with some pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HWE kernel versions can be seen in [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) article.

[image]

[image]